# Hide Column in Gridview Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show/hide a column in a table created by a asp.net Gridview. I've tried these 3 examples and can't get any of them to work. I'm not seeing an error message; the column remains visible.  If I change the column class to HeaderStyle-CssClass="colDefinitionHide" ItemStyle-CssClass="colDefinitionHide" the column is hidden when the page loads but I can't get it to toggle  hidden/visible. Thanks

```
   .colDefinitionHide {
       display: none;
    }

    .colDefinitionShow {
       display: block;
    }

    <div>                  
      <button id="hide">Hide</button>
      <button id="show">Show</button>                    
    </div>

    <asp:GridView ID="grdScoring" runat="server">
    <Columns>          
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test" HeaderStyle-CssClass="colDefinition" ItemStyle-CssClass="colDefinition">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='Test'  />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    Example 1:

    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $(".colDefinition").hide();
    });

    $("#show").click(function () {
        $(".colDefinition").show(); 
    }); 
     
    Example 2:

    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $(".colDefinition").toggle();
    }); 
     
    Example 3:
     
    $("#hide").click(function () {
        $(".colDefinition").addClass("colDefinitionHide");
    });

     $("#show").click(function () {
         $(".colDefinition").removeClass("colDefinitionShow");
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a type="button" attribute to the buttons. Without it, it was causing the page to postback/resubmit and the whole table was reloading.

```
<button id="hide" type="button">Hide</button>
```